# Nested IF statement returns #VALUE

Tags: excel, if-statement, vba

I have a pre-recorded macro that needs to be modified. It uses an `IF` statement to check if the value is `N/A` and changes it to 0, unless it begins with `CN`, then it sets the cell to the `CN*` value. I need the `IF` statement to check for `CN*` or `V*` and return the value of either.

The `IF` statement needs to check if the value is `N/A` and change the cell to 0, otherwise if the value begins with `CN` or `V` it needs to return that value.

Base statement:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(""CN*"",RC[1]:RC[2],2,FALSE))=TRUE,0,VLOOKUP(""CN*"",RC[1]:RC[2],2,FALSE))"
```

Modified satement:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(""CN*"",RC[1]:RC[2],2,FALSE))=TRUE,0,VLOOKUP(""CN*"",RC[1]:RC[2],2,FALSE)) ORIF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(""V*"",RC[1]:RC[2],2,FALSE))=TRUE,0,VLOOKUP(""V*"",RC[1]:RC[2],2,FALSE))"
```

Currently the base statement returns 0 normally but does not check for values that start with `V*`. The modified statement returns `#VALUE!`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to mousio's answer, you might also use `IFERROR` instead of simply `IF`, since you recompute the value obtained from the condition. For the first one, it will be:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(""CN*"",RC[1]:RC[2],2,FALSE),0)"
```

Which means that if `VLOOKUP(""CN*"",RC[1]:RC[2],2,FALSE)` returns an error, you get `0` instead, and if not, you get the value of `VLOOKUP(""CN*"",RC[1]:RC[2],2,FALSE)`.

And the modified one:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(""CN*"",RC[1]:RC[2],2,FALSE),
      IFERROR(VLOOKUP(""V*"",RC[1]:RC[2],2,FALSE),
      0))"
```

In this one, if `VLOOKUP(""CN*"",RC[1]:RC[2],2,FALSE)` returns an error, it checks for `VLOOKUP(""V*"",RC[1]:RC[2],2,FALSE)`, and if this returns an error too, it returns `0`.

Answer (score 1):

I would think you need to replace your first `0` result by your new check, i.e. replace this single `if`:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(""CN*"",RC[1]:RC[2],2,FALSE))=TRUE,
      0,
      VLOOKUP(""CN*"",RC[1]:RC[2],2,FALSE))"
```

by this *nested* `if`:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(""CN*"",RC[1]:RC[2],2,FALSE))=TRUE,
      IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(""V*"",RC[1]:RC[2],2,FALSE))=TRUE,
        0,
        VLOOKUP(""V*"",RC[1]:RC[2],2,FALSE)),
      VLOOKUP(""CN*"",RC[1]:RC[2],2,FALSE))"
```

(adjusted for readability)

It might be more clear if you then invert the conditions and switch remaining `if` arguments:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(""CN*"",RC[1]:RC[2],2,FALSE))=FALSE,
      VLOOKUP(""CN*"",RC[1]:RC[2],2,FALSE),
      IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(""V*"",RC[1]:RC[2],2,FALSE))=FALSE,
        VLOOKUP(""V*"",RC[1]:RC[2],2,FALSE),
        0))"
```